# JS - My table does not appear anything. I wanna show TR after TD. WHY I cant do it?

Tags: javascript

Hello can you guys point out my fault ? I just wanna show my td and tr therefore I created a variable called **variavel** but it does not return anything in my html.

```js
var lista = [

{ "descricao":"arroz","qtd":"1" , "valor":"5.40"   }, 
{ "descricao":"cerveja","qtd":"12" , "valor":"1.99"   },
{ "descricao":"carne","qtd":"1" , "valor":"15.00"   }

];


function listas (lista) 
{
 total = 0;

 for (var key in lista)

 {
      total+= lista[key].valor * lista[key].qtd;
   
 }
 return total;
}


function criatabela(lista) 
{  
 // var tabelabody = document.createElement('table');
 // tabelabody.id="tabelalista";
 var tabela = '<thead><tr><td>DESCRICAO</td><td>QUANTIDADE</td><td>VALOR</td><td>EDITAR | ACAO </td></tr></thead><tbody>';

 for (var key in lista)
 {
  tabela +='<tr> <td> '+lista[key].descricao+' </td> <td> '+lista[key].qtd+' </td><td> '+lista[key].valor+' </td><td>  </td></tr>';
  alert(lista[key].descricao);
  alert(lista[key].qtd);
  alert(lista[key].valor);
 }

 tabela +='</tbody>';
 
 document.getElementById('tabelalista') = tabela;



}
listas(lista);
criatabela(lista);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>  Shopping Control </title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/config.js" > </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js" > </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css"> 

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" id="navTitulo" href="index.html" >    </a>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="container-fluid"> 
 
<table id="tabelalista" class="table">  

</table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

is my js written by **wrong way** ? Please help me!

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the innerHTML of the table equal to your tabela variable.

```
document.getElementById('tabelalista').innerHTML = tabela;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `innerHTML` in this line:

```
document.getElementById('tabelalista').innerHTML = tabela;
```

```js
var lista = [

{ "descricao":"arroz","qtd":"1" , "valor":"5.40"   }, 
{ "descricao":"cerveja","qtd":"12" , "valor":"1.99"   },
{ "descricao":"carne","qtd":"1" , "valor":"15.00"   }

];


function listas (lista) 
{
 total = 0;

 for (var key in lista)

 {
      total+= lista[key].valor * lista[key].qtd;
   
 }
 return total;
}


function criatabela(lista) 
{  
 // var tabelabody = document.createElement('table');
 // tabelabody.id="tabelalista";
 var tabela = '<thead><tr><td>DESCRICAO</td><td>QUANTIDADE</td><td>VALOR</td><td>EDITAR | ACAO </td></tr></thead><tbody>';

 for (var key in lista)
 {
  tabela +='<tr> <td> '+lista[key].descricao+' </td> <td> '+lista[key].qtd+' </td><td> '+lista[key].valor+' </td><td>  </td></tr>';
 }

 tabela +='</tbody>';
 
 document.getElementById('tabelalista').innerHTML = tabela;



}
listas(lista);
criatabela(lista);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>  Shopping Control </title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/config.js" > </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js" > </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css"> 

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" id="navTitulo" href="index.html" >    </a>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="container-fluid"> 
 
<table id="tabelalista" class="table">  

</table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see in your developer console, you will notice a reference error. That's because you can't assign html like this. You need to user .innerHTML or .append() (if using jquery)

```js
var lista = [

{ "descricao":"arroz","qtd":"1" , "valor":"5.40"   }, 
{ "descricao":"cerveja","qtd":"12" , "valor":"1.99"   },
{ "descricao":"carne","qtd":"1" , "valor":"15.00"   }

];


function listas (lista) 
{
 total = 0;

 for (var key in lista)

 {
      total+= lista[key].valor * lista[key].qtd;
   
 }
 return total;
}


function criatabela(lista) 
{  
 // var tabelabody = document.createElement('table');
 // tabelabody.id="tabelalista";
 var tabela = '<thead><tr><td>DESCRICAO</td><td>QUANTIDADE</td><td>VALOR</td><td>EDITAR | ACAO </td></tr></thead><tbody>';

 for (var key in lista)
 {
  tabela +='<tr> <td> '+lista[key].descricao+' </td> <td> '+lista[key].qtd+' </td><td> '+lista[key].valor+' </td><td>  </td></tr>';
  
    }

 tabela +='</tbody>';
 document.getElementById('tabelalista').innerHTML = (tabela); //Note this. 



}
console.log(document.getElementById('tabelalista'))
listas(lista);
criatabela(lista);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>  Shopping Control </title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/config.js" > </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js" > </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css"> 

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" id="navTitulo" href="index.html" >    </a>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="container-fluid"> 
 
<table id="tabelalista" class="table">  

</table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did it , but I get this message; 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: Not sure what's wrong. I m able to run this snippet (click on run this snippet) as it is and its working. Can you provide more info ?